# Is there a way to create qml filedialog with specific localization settings?

Tags: python, qt, qml

I am currently looking for a way to create qml File Dialog with specific language. E.g. my system language is English, but I want to launch my file dialog in Spanish.
Is there a way to do that in qml?

I have tried using .qm files and qtlinguist, but it seems not to be robust. Additionally, this approach is not able to translate all details and buttons in the file dialog window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this with python, but I'm sure it is easy for you to translate it to python. Have a look into [Locating Qt Translations](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/internationalization.html#locating-qt-translations).

The translations for all Qt components/widgets are stored in your Qt install. For me the path is `Qt/6.4.0/gcc_64/translations`.

I managed to translate all strings in the `FileDialog` by doing the following.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QLibraryInfo>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator qtTranslator;
    if (qtTranslator.load(QLocale("es"),
                          "qtbase",
                          "_",
                          QLibraryInfo::path(QLibraryInfo::TranslationsPath))) {
        app.installTranslator(&qtTranslator);
    }

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/75067972/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
        &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
            if (!obj && url == objUrl)
                QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Dialogs

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: qsTr("File Dialog")
        onClicked: fileDialog.open()
    }

    FileDialog { id: fileDialog }
}
```

Keep in mind that if you want to deploy your application you must include the translations in your project via CMake or qmake.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! When I test it I will leave a comment and mark your answer as correct if it helps to solve a problem.